# What is the significance of this method as: public <T> T methodName(parameters)

Tags: java, generics

What is the significance of this method as:

```
public <T> T methodName(parameters)
```

Comment: It's significant for use cases like [Collections.emptyList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList())

Comment: Sebastian is right. Also, it can be used like `Collections.<MyType>emptyList()` to get the result with the type you want.

Comment: @Vincent. Although that is fine. But the type is inferred by the compiler based on the type of the List you are assigning the result to.

Comment: @pravin kumar is this answer satisfies you?

Answer (score 5):

**Generic Methods:**

You can write a single generic method declaration that can be called with arguments of different types. Based on the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, the compiler handles each method call appropriately. Following are the rules to define Generic Methods:

1. All generic method declarations have a type parameter section delimited by angle brackets (< and >) that precedes the method's return type ( < E > in the next example).
2. Each type parameter section contains one or more type parameters separated by commas. A type parameter, also known as a type variable, is an identifier that specifies a generic type name.
3. The type parameters can be used to declare the return type and act as placeholders for the types of the arguments passed to the generic method, which are known as actual type arguments.
4. A generic method's body is declared like that of any other method. Note that type parameters can represent only reference types not primitive types (like int, double and char).

You can Read  more  [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) ,[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm) ,[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Answer (score 0):

Generic implementation.

Conside this [example from docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

> **Bounded type parameters are key to the implementation of generic algorithms**. Consider the following method that counts the number of elements in an array T[] that are greater than a specified element elem.

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)  // compiler error
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```